# I am facing two errors in this code help me to solve it

Tags: ios, swift, background

Code:

```
var bgTask: BackgroundTaskManager! = UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler({() -> Void in
print("ending background task")
UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(self.bgTask)
self.bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
})
self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(
            60, 
            target: self.locationManager, 
            selector: #selector(self.startUpdatingLocation), 
            userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `self.bgTask`,`self.timer`,`self.locationManager` etc then you have to declare it globally something like,

```
var bgTask: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier! = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier()

var timer: NSTimer! = NSTimer()

var locationManager : CLLocationManager!  = CLLocationManager()
```

Second thing `var bgTask: BackgroundTaskManager!` is wrong, it should be `var bgTask: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier!`

Comment: solve thi problem with ueing other supporting file